# Passing arbitrary parameters on user registration with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, strong-parameters, mixpanel

I'm using Devise 4.2.1 with Rails 5.1. Our app uses MixPanel's JavaScript library which gives anonymous website visitors a unique ID as they browse around.

When a user creates an account, we link their anonymous ID to their known user ID in our database. We do this by inserting the user's anonymous `mixpanel_id` in a hidden field on the registration form, and posting it along with the other sign up data to Devise's registrations controller:

```
= vertical_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name) do |f|
  = f.input :name
  = f.input :email
  = f.input :password
  = f.input :mixpanel_id, as: :hidden, input_html: { value: '' }

:javascript
  after_load_once(function () {
    mixpanel_promise.then(function (mixpanel) {
      var id = mixpanel.get_distinct_id();
      $('#user_mixpanel_id').val(id);
    });
  });
```

Then we override the create method in Devise:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def create
    super

    if resource.valid?
      $mixpanel.alias(resource.id, params[:user][:mixpanel_id]) if params[:user][:mixpanel_id]
    end
  end
end
```

This seems to have been working okay for us. People are indeed linked and we can track their behavior right through the site, although I have noticed some weird behavior where people haven't been linked correctly. While investigating today I noticed something in the logs: `Unpermitted parameter: :mixpanel_id`

I looked into strong parameters, but because `:mixpanel_id` is not a stored attribute on the user, I'm not sure how I can add it as a permitted parameter here:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:name])
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Unpermitted parameter: :mixpanel_id
>
> I looked into strong parameters, but because :mixpanel_id is not a
> stored attribute on the user, I'm not sure how I can add it as a
> permitted parameter here

You could do this by adding `attr_accessor :mixpanel_id` to your `User` model

```
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :mixpanel_id
end
```

and permitting it in the strong parameters

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:name, :mixpanel_id])
end
```

Comment: Legend! Thank you. That's what I was missing.